# Bevel Operation/Shading Problem

Tags: shaders, bevel

Im making a guitar slanted guitar cabinet. Im having some weird bevel issues shown below.

[image]

The corners have a weird shading issue. This is whats happening at the corners:
[image]

I can kind of fix it by unchecking "loop slide" in the bevel operator, and i get this result: [image]

It fixes most of the problem, but there is still a corner with weird shading.

My normals are all blue, no extra verts and scale is 1.000. No clue whats going on.

I added a basic cube and added an edge loop in the middle, then pulled one side back and still got the same thing:

[image]

Any ideas why this is happening? Thanks!

EDIT: i turned the bevel shape to 0.900 and the 2 effected corners are exaggerated. Why are just those 2 corners not beveling right?

[image]

I have recalculated the normals too and they are fine. I have started from scratch and then i get different results as to which corners have the "bad" shading

Comment: hello maybe share your original object? https://pasteall.org/blend/ ... have your shade smooth your object? are there edges overlapping?

Comment: Hello :). I can confirm this issue - the shading gets progresively weirder with increasing number of segments.

Comment: Here is the blend:
https://pasteall.org/blend/e88b3bc458894adc863a3bf14b103ad8

Comment: Maybe  like [this](https://pasteall.org/blend/d4b5bd6d012a4f3994841e7be8a7ddea). Side horizontal loops optional, just there for all quads, subdiv workflow.

Comment: Thanks @RobinBetts. I never think to use subdiv for these kinds of things. Usually the bevel works fine. I will give this workflow a shot, thanks! Also i got a better result using a boolen for the angle cut. I only had the back, bottom right corner with the shading artifact.

Answer (score 0):

I can't point out the exact issue without the blend file. My best guess is that you should check the harden normals checkbox in the bevel or use the weighted normals modifier.

Comment: https://pasteall.org/blend/e88b3bc458894adc863a3bf14b103ad8 @maulik sharma